# Service broker and SignalR problema catch notification

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to do an example in C # of signalR and service broker, everything is just like the examples I've seen on youtube and on the net, but something is happening that the onchange event of the sqldependency class does not capture the changes I make in the Table of my database ... some idea or suggestion that can give me ....

Comment: You might want to provide an example of the code that is giving you a problem.

Comment: It may help to simplify your solution, take out SignalR and just log (Console.Write for example) to rule out any issues with SignalR.

Comment: The problem is not in the code, the problem at my discretion is in sql, as the sqldependency class does not capture the onchange event, when I make any changes to the table of the bd, however when I remove the bd if the onchange event is triggered Of sqldependency, I hope with this explanation to see been more explicit